# Как правильно настроить apt pinning в debian?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, dpkg, deb

**Цель:** чтобы установка пакетов подчинялась определенным мной правилам и при установке не надо было указывать откуда ставить.
**Правила (примерные):**

1. Если пакет есть в jessie backports, то ставить из jessie backports
2. Если пакета в jessie backports нету, то ставить из стандартных
   репозиториев
3. С foobar.com ставить пакет foobar и некоторые его
   зависимости независимо от того, есть ли они в родных репозиториях
   debian'а
4. Больше никаких пакетов с foobar.com не ставить

   ```
   # cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
   APT::Default-Release "jessie";

   # cat /etc/apt/preferences
   Package: foobar dependence1 dependence2
   Pin: origin "foobar.com"
   Pin-Priority: 993

   Package: *
   Pin: origin "foobar.com"
   Pin-Priority: -10

   Package: *
   Pin: release n=jessie
   Pin-Priority: 500

   Package: *
   Pin: release n=jessie-backports
   Pin-Priority: 999

   Package: *
   Pin: release n=jessie-updates
   Pin-Priority: 500
   ```

**Вопросы:**

1. Все ли я правильно сделал?
2. Не отвалятся ли рядовые обновления системы/обновления безопасности с security.debian.org?
3. Может, я чего-нибудь не вижу, и есть способ сделать это изящнее?
4. Больший приоритет (в рамках одного диапазона, описанного в man apt_preferences) означает больший приоритет источника? Например, пакет есть в двух репозиториях. У одного приоритет 991, у второго 992. Пакет будет ставиться из репозитория с приоритетом 992?